# Express.JS,Node.JS- Variable accessible for each request Scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, variables

I have a node.js express application where I need to have a language variable which specifies which language the data should be sent back for each request.

1) I want to access this language variable across all files within the scope of that request.
2) I don't want this variable to change once it has been set for that particular request.

The solution I Tried:
1) Singleton classes: When I created a singleton class and tried to import this class, its persists across multiple requests.

eg:

```
const Constants = require("../util/constants.js");
let instance =null;
let  language = new WeakMap();
class Global{
    constructor(){
        if(!instance){
            instance=this;
        }
        return instance;
    }
    get language(){
        return language.get(this);
    }
    set language(value){
        if(language.get(this)!==undefined){
            throw Error("Language Already Set");
        }else{
            language.set(this,value);
        }
    }
}
module.exports = new Global();
```

Please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Why don't you just attach the language to the request object and pass the request object around?  Technically it's mutable, but your code really shouldn't mutate variables passed into it.

Answer (score -1):

you can add that variable in .env file then u can access it across you application
.by adding   require('dotenv').config() in your server.js file and qqaccess th variable where eve y need by process.env.your varaible name

Comment: This is not specific to a request.